H-bridge motor braking via NC button
New guy here. I'm doing some work for an engineering professor; he wants me to implement stop/braking capability on the robot we are working on. The platform used is a Pioneer 3-DX, with two motors being controlled by their respective h-bridges. I have a 1NC e-stop, which when pressed should somehow cause the motors to brake and bring the robot to a halt.
The e-stop is rated at 2.5A, while the motor datasheet appears to say its stall current is ~12A. That 12A I'm not sure the h-bridges can handle, and I'm definitely sure a rapid stop would fry the little e-stop.
My idea was to use a relay to manage the current going through the e-stop. To get the motor to brake, could I cause a short across the windings (like a 0101 signal)? I don't really know much about relays or implementing stop functionality, so any help would be appreciated.
Here are the links to the Pioneer 3-DX and motor. Please let me know if you need any more info. Thanks!

The motor has a stall current listed at 12.1 amperes, which is simply the current in a locked rotor and can be calculated from the voltage divided by the terminal resistance (15.1 / 1.26).  Since the motor has a torque constant of 3.29 oz-in/amp, if you are running at 15.1 volts you will have 12.1*3.29 or about 40 oz-in of braking torque the instant you short out the motor.  If these are DC brush motors, this type of braking can be hard on the brushes, so you may want to externally limit your braking current.
Keep in mind that as the rotor speed decreases, the back EMF decreases (2.43 V/krpm), and your maximum braking current from this method is the back EMF divided by the terminal resistance.  This current is applied to your torque constant, so your braking torque decreases as the motor slows down.  The energy from the braking action is dissipated in the motor itself as heat.
If you limit your current to 2.5 amps with a current limiter, you can provide 8.2 oz-in of braking torque (3.29 * 2.5) until your motor back EMF drops to a voltage too low to allow 2.5 amps to flow.  This would occur at a back EMF of 3.15 volts (2.5 * 1.26).  Since your back EMF constant is 2.43 v/krpm, you will hit 3.15 volts at 1296 RPM.  Unless you want to do active braking, you will brake with 8.2 oz-in until you slow to 1296 RPM, after which the braking torque will be proportional to the shaft speed.
Also keep in mind that this value will be lower if your motor is hot, as the terminal resistance will increase.
Good luck!

Gotcha. I had a suspicion hard stopping the motor via shorting would put wear and tear on it. I'll likely have to talk with the professor to see if he really, really wants hard stop capability. I looked further at the Pioneer 3DX documentation and there's a designated e-stop location I could solder the button to, which should allow me to cut power to the motors (wouldn't brake them, but it should be easier to implement). Thanks for the response!
